# form submit on each button click

Tags: php, html

My code is

```
<form action="test.php" name="test">
<?php foreach($result as $res)
{
 ?>
  <div>
  <label><?php echo $res->name;?></label>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $res->val;?>">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
<?php }
?>
</form>
```

I need the same action for each submit button, whenever user clicks on it the action `test.php` should be called.
I have tried like this but it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: input tags are not closed correctly...

Comment: what action? defined where? how ?

Comment: @mindandmedia: Not necessary in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each submit, you need a different form. Here you go:

```
<?php foreach($result as $res)
{
echo "<form action=\"test.php\" name=\"".$res->name."\">";
 ?>
  <div>
  <label><?php echo $res->name;?></label>
  <input type="text" name="<php echo $res->val;?>">
  <input type="submit" value="submit"
  </div>
<?php
echo "</form>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: @Dagon: R U sure?? Could you please tell how??

Comment: hey guys, i just need that each button should perform same action

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: I know the syntax,it is just a typing mistake